# PHP Include Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте, я решил через массив сделать подключить на HTML сайт JS скрипты.
Вот мой код:
**aengines.php**

```
<?php
    $aengines = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'audioplayercss' => 'https://site.com/audioplayerengine/initaudioplayer-1.css',
            'audioplayerjs' => 'https://site.com/audioplayerengine/initaudioplayer-1.js'
        ],
    ];
?>
```

**audioengineJS.php**

```
<?php
include('aengines.php');
 ?>
<?php foreach ($aengines as $aenginejs): ?>
        <script src="<?php echo $aenginejs['audioplayerjs']; ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include('../../assets/php/audioengineJS.php'); ?>
```

Пробовал я сувать этот include в Header и даже после /body, но ничего.

Что я делаю не так? При импорте CSS все работает, а при JS не работает. ***P.S в массиве около 30 елементов, я удалил лишние чтобы много текста не занимало.***

Comment: `Что я делаю не так?` - а что не так?  `при JS не работает` - что не работает? а как должно работать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский может где-то я допустил ошибку? Потому-что ничего не отображается на сайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте подключить js таким образом:

```
<script><?php echo file_get_contents('myFile.js'); ?></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант полностью рабочий http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfbcabfd8d62704be4f9d22608f53839d12c5548

Поэтому смотрите на пути к include